# How do I set a gridview column to use email links dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

If I were to use html to set a column to use email addresses I could do this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="mailto:<%# Bind("email") %>"><%# Bind("email") %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

How do I do this Dynamically? I have tried doing

```
e.Row.Cells[8].Text = "<a href='mailto:" + Eval(EMAIL_ADDRESS) + "'>" + Eval(EMAIL_ADDRESS) + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor myAnchor = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
myAnchor.HRef = string.Format("mailto:{0}", myEmailAddress);
myAnchor.InnerText = myEmailAddress;
e.Row.Cells[8].Conntrols.Add(myAnchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string emailAddy = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
string strEM = "<a href='mailto:" + emailAddy + "'>" + emailAddy + "</a>";
e.Row.Cells[8].Text = strEM;
```